# How to enable category hierarchy for links?

Tags: categories, links, hierarchical

It looks that by default WordPress had hierarchy only for page/post categories and not for links categories.

How can I enable that?

Answer (score 1):

You can not enable that, it is not supported, on top of that there is no meta table for links :)

For one of my sites: http://populair.eu I wanted to put each link you see on there in a hierarchical category (obvious if you see the layout). But since it was not supported I put all links in another format and wrote a template to display them in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a plugin called [Hierarchical Link Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hierarchical-link-categories/) that enables that functionality. Check it out!